# surface area of domain delimited by two lines and two non concentric circles

Tags: integration, geometry, circles, area, arc-length

I am looking for a way to estimate the area of this "sector-like" surface between two non concentric circles delimited by arbitrary segments:

[image: shell]

I'm interested in both a methodology to calculate the area of the highlighted surface in Cartesian or polar coordinates and more importantly an expression or an approximation as good as possible in terms of the line segments length and arcs length.

In fact this is derived from a concrete situation where I can easily measure these parameters but only roughly estimate radius and arcs angles, and even less coordinates, needed for a more formal calculation.

Anyway, I don't even find how to start, I tried different approaches but with no success, plus I have to express this area using a limited set of accessible parameters. My math are from a long time ago, as is my english!, so any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Edit:

Why the down vote, did you look at the picture at least to give some advice...

Anyway, I lightened the post a bit and I can try to formalize this a little more. So, consider 2 arbitrary circles and 2 arbitrary lines, how could I get the area of the domain delimited by their intersections? (shape is real, there is 4 intersection points)

- $(\mathscr{C_0}) : r=R_0$
- $(\mathscr{C_1}) : r=\delta\cos(\theta-\varphi)+\sqrt{R_1^2-\delta^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi)}$
- $(\mathscr{D_0}) : r=d_0/\sin(\theta-\theta_0)$
- $(\mathscr{D_1}) : r=d_1/\sin(\theta-\theta_1)$

or

- $(\mathscr{C_0}) : x^2+y^2=R_0^2$
- $(\mathscr{C_1}) : (x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=R_1^2$
- $(\mathscr{D_0}) : y=a_0x+b_0$
- $(\mathscr{D_1}) : y=a_1x+b_1$

$(\delta,\varphi)=(x_1,y_1)$ position of $(\mathscr{C_1})$ from the origin
$(d_i,\theta_i)$ are distance and angle of $(\mathscr{D_i})$ from the origin
if I'm not wrong...

Comment: You mean "non-concentric" circles. "Eccentric" means something else.

Comment: Can you measure the circumference of either circle? Or are you restricted to just the two arcs?

Comment: One trick - if it is possible - is to measure straightline distances between points on the circles. If you can do this, then finding the straightline distances between three known points on the circle (the more well-separated the better) is enough information to find the radius and center of that circle. Even if you can only do it for one of the circles, that would be useful information.

Comment: @paul-sinclair:  rectified, thx (double meaning in my language). As for the circumference, no, but I still can estimate radii by guessing position of the origin, even if it is gross approximation, if I could get an explicit expression for the area of the shape I should make some estimations.

Comment: @paul-sinclair Concerning your third comment, are you referring to the cords length? Same thing I should get an approximation. To clarify situation, imagine the shape is part of a road turn, hard to walk inside! not possible to walk outside, at least everywhere :) Approximations from some explicit integrals should do the trick if I can emphasize these parameters even if it depends also of the radii and arc angles.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the known information is:

- There are two circles of different radii.
- One of the circles lies inside the other, but they are not concentric.
- Two radii of the inner circle are extended to intersect the outer circle, forming an annular sector.
- the lengths of the four boundaries of that region are known.

Unfortunately this is not enough information to determine the area. Consider this thought experiment:

1. Enlarge the radius of the small circle by some small amount.
2. Leave the radius for $d_1$ where it is, but move the radius for $d_2$ around until the arc on the inner circle is back to length $L_1$.
3. On the radius for $d_1$, plot the point that is a distance of $d_1$ away from the inner circle. Move the outer circle over until it passes through this point again.
4. "Pin" the outer circle at this point. It can rotate around the point, and it can be enlarged by moving its center away from this point, but that point will continue to lie on the circle.
5. Rotate the outer circle around the pinned point until the distance between the two circles along the second radius is $d_2$.
6. If the arc on the outer circle is not $L_2$, then increase or decrease the radius by moving the center away from or towards the pinned point, until the outer circle arc is of length $L_2$
7. The previous step will have changed the other distance away from $d_2$, so go back to step 5. Keep repeating until both distances converge to the values $d_2$ and $L_2$ (and they will converge).

If you were to somehow actually do this process, you would end up with another annular sector with the same four dimensions, but a different shape. I cannot say just from this that the shape will also have a different area, but it is likely to be the case. What this demonstrates is that those four measurements are not enough to fix the shape of this region.

We need one more measurement - a measurement that is not completely determined by the four you already know. Without knowing what your situation is, I cannot say what measurements you can get. Ones that would be useful include

- the circumference of either circle.
- The straight-line distance between any two corners of your region, except the two straight sides we already know.
- straight line distances between any three well-separated points on the inner circle, or between any three well-separated points on the outer circle. (Since this introduces new points for the referents of the measurements, all three measurements will be needed.) From those distances, one can calculate the radius of one of the circles, which is enough to lock down the shape.

Comment: thank you for your effort. Not clear on the figure but no, inner circle radii are not extended to intersect outer circle, straight line segments are arbitrary, sorry for the confusion. About the other parameters I can guess some estimations; if I could get some expression then I should play with values and estimate some uncertainty. I guess it involves elliptic integrals so either way I will use approx to get more usable equation 'for field work'. Problem is how to get some explicit expression given this domain of integration unless some geometric relations will do the trick.

Comment: There really isn't a good integral you can set up without knowing the center of the outer circle. "Straight line segments are arbitrary" means "straight line segments are worthless trash I'm pretending are meaningful". You need to either figure out how to make them non-arbitrary, or give this up altogether.

Comment: If I had known these lines are at arbitrary orientations, I could have given a far simpler demonstration that you don't have enough information. Simply consider there to be hinges at each of the corners. Clearly this is not a rigid shape and can be bent to give a wide range of areas. With this, you will need two more measurements, not one, to fix the shape and have a well-defined area. Further that additional measurement will need to be something that makes the shape rigid.